# How to count fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity and pager adapter in it which displays 3 fragments. The fragments are shuffled. I need to know the number of each page when I am swiping through them and that number needs to be displayed in a textView. For example, when I am in the first page number 1 is displayed, second page - number 2 and so on.

**PagerAdapter.java**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        return this.fragments.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    public void setFragments(List<Fragment> fragments) {
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }
}
```

**mainActivity.java**

```
    public class testActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_pager_adapter);
            initialisePaging();
        }

        private  void initialisePaging() {
            List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment1.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment2.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment3.class.getName()));
            PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        Collections.shuffle(fragments, new Random(System.nanoTime()));

            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_test, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want to be displaying the number in your fragment, use this**

In your Activity

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // Here you can add an argument that will be passed to the fragment
    // In your case you need to pass the page number
    Fragment fragment = this.fragments.get(arg0);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("page_number", position);
    fragment.setArguments(b);
    return fragment;
}
```

In you fragment do this

```
int number;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Read the data that Activity passed to us
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            number = args.getInt("page_number") + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        number = savedInstanceState.getInt("page_number");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Here you need to find your TextView and show the number
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, container, false);
    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.someTextView)).setText(String.format("%d", number));
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("page_number", number);
}
```

**If you want to be displaying the number in your Activity, use this**

```
private  void initialisePaging() {
    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment1.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment2.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment3.class.getName()));
    PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    Collections.shuffle(fragments, new Random(System.nanoTime()));

    // !!! Change ME!!!!!
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.someTextView);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            textView.setText("Position: " + i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });

    pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);


}
```

Comment: What should I write after onPageSelected?

Comment: see my edit, I have pointed you to a project of mine. I hate to copy myself ;)

Comment: It's still not clear to me. Note that I don't want to do anything with the fragments. I just need a textView to display the page's number(not the fragments, I don't care about their order). When I am swiping from left to right that number needs to grow and when I am swiping from right to left that number needs to decrease.

Comment: I think that first piece of code should be written in PagerAdapter.java. However somehow it cannot resolve symbol 'position'. What should I do?

Comment: change arg0 to position, my bad

Comment: It's still not working. When I am trying to swipe the program turns off. In my logcat it says that the problem is in this line: _((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView115)).setText(String.format("%d", number));_

Comment: I have just understood that the testView should be located in the fragment. But wouldn't it be much easier, if the textView would be located in the PagerAdapter activity? Is there a simple way to rewrite the code? If not I could leave it like this.

Comment: I have changed the code. You need to put a textview in your activity then.

Comment: Then close the question by checking (accepting) my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `PageChangeListener` as:

```
yourPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

     @Override
     public void onPageSelected(int position)
     {
         yourTextView.setText("Page: " + position); 
     }

     ... ... 

  });
```

Comment: Yes this is easy and perfect solution I suppose